# Xamarin Android Error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever I try to use NewtonSoft.Json in my Xamarin Forms Android project it prints out the following error

> 1>No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=snip" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=snip". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=snip" arbitrarily.
>   1>Found conflicts between different versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
>   1>The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
>   1>The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
>   1>The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
>   1>Done building project "SocialNetwork.Android.csproj".

I tried looking in the project .Android (Android Properties) for something that says 7.1 to update to 8.0 since I'm guessing that's what the log is trying to say

But in the application tab the option for "Compile using Android Version (Target Framework)" only has an option for 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Found conflicts between different versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that
>   could not be resolved.

I think this error occurred because Projects in your Solution  includes different versions of  Newtonsoft.Json dll.
if the problem case by that best thing to do is uninstall Newtonsoft.Json  from both xamarin.android and xamarin.forms project and install again with newer version. if your solution have other platform project their Newtonsoft.Json  dll also should uninstall.

And also update your xamarin.Forms dll to the latest version.

> "But in the application tab the option for "Compile using Android
>   Version (Target Framework)" only has an option for 7.1"

Install Latest SDK platform "API 26" from SDK Manager

Comment: I tried reinstalling it with the latest version (Which it current was) and didn't work. Also when I click the Android SDK Manager it asks if I want Command Processor Window to make changes to my device upon clicking Yes it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Just create new project solution.
Close it.
navigate to projects
delete existing forms android project and copy paste your old project.
Now open new project and try to Rebuild.